# Apex trigger before update generate problem with Aura methode

Tags: apex, trigger, aura, before-trigger, error-messages

My trigger beforeUpdate cause me a problem , i have a button in the header named Validate and this button call the methode below 'UpdateHeader' , but when the user is not the AdminUser , he can validate because of the trigger and the error message appear and exactly this message of the error method (teste_ErrorMessage) , and if i make my trigger as inactive all user can validate with out any error message ,

How can i modify my code .

=> the trigger :

```
trigger BeforeUpdate on Form__c (before update) {
    
      Id currentUser = UserInfo.getUserId();
    
     Id currentUserProfileId = userinfo.getProfileId();
    
     String profileName = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id = :currentUserProfileId].Name;
    
    
        
     if (profileName !=' Admin Key-User'){
    
     for (CORE_Form__c form : trigger.old )
        
    {
                system.debug('teste');

         // if(Trigger.isupdate){}

        if(form.CreatedById != currentUser)
        {
            form.addError(' non modifié - ');
        } 
        
         if(form.CreatedById == currentUser && form.Status__c  == 'Validated')
        {
            form.addError(' non modifié - le statut Validé');
        } 
        

    }

    }   }
```

=> The aura methode :

```
updateHeader : function(cmp, event, formStatus) {               
        var hideNotification = $A.get("e.c:CORE_MTO_EVT_HideNotificationMessage");
        hideNotification.fire();
        
        $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("loadingSpinner"), "slds-hide");
       
        var FormHeader = cmp.get("v.FormHeader");
        FormHeader.CORE_Status__c = formStatus;
        
        var action = cmp.get("c.updateForm");        
        action.setParams({
            "form" : FormHeader,                      
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("loadingSpinner"), "slds-hide");
            if (cmp.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {              
                var FormUpd = response.getReturnValue();         
                cmp.set("v.FormHeader", FormUpd);
                if (formStatus == 'Validated') {
                    cmp.set("v.isLocked",true);
                    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("validate"), "slds-hide");
                    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("validateBottom"), "slds-hide");
                    if (cmp.set("v.isAdminUser")==true) {
                        $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("unvalidate"), "slds-hide");
                        $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("unvalidateBottom"), "slds-hide");
                    }                    
                }                   
                if (formStatus == 'Finished') {
                    cmp.set("v.isLocked",false);
                    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("unvalidate"), "slds-hide");
                    $A.util.addClass(cmp.find("unvalidateBottom"), "slds-hide");
                    $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("validate"), "slds-hide");
                    $A.util.removeClass(cmp.find("validateBottom"), "slds-hide");
                }
                
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                this.offline(cmp, event);                   
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
               this.error(cmp, event, response);              
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
 
    error : function(cmp, event, response) {
        var errors = response.getError();
        var errormessage = "";
        if (errors) {
            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                errormessage = errors[0].message;
            }
        } else {
            errormessage = "Unknown error";
        }
        var notification = $A.get("e.c:CORE_MTO_EVT_NotificationMessage");                
        notification.setParams({ 
            "message" : $A.get("$Label.c.teste_ErrorMessage") + errormessage,
            "style" : "slds-theme--error"
        });
        notification.fire();        
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (profileName !=' Admin Key-User'){
```

Fields retrieved from the database cannot start or end with whitespace. As such, this condition can never be false, so the validation shall always occur. One must be careful to pay attention to strings carefully while writing code.

```
 if (profileName != 'Admin Key-User') {
```

Comment: thanks  , i remove the espace , but still have the same problem